# How to transmit a headless window browser from a remote server to my local computer?

Tags: linux, selenium, headless, browser-automation

I have several remote servers on which I run headless Chromium browsers. I've begun to need to be able to see the actual browser windows from the remote servers and be able to interract with them. On my local computer. 
At least I want to see the remote browser windows.

Is that possible at all?

The remote servers have no physical monitor/screen.

Comment: which version of selenium ?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel the latest one

Comment: If you need to interact with them then you may as well run a local browser with a dev console. You can snap screenshots using selenium and scp them back to your local machine.

Answer (score 2):

There are several docker images of selenium for debugging, using VNC.

Here's the [link](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium#debugging) to their github.

When you run the image, don't forget to bind the port for VNC.

> docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -p **VNC_PORT**:5900 [...]

You can then download a VNC viewer [here](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/).
You'll just have to specifcy the hostname and port of your remote machine and you're ready to go.

**EDIT:** If you don't have docker and if you really don't want to install it, here the [link](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/node-chrome-debug/dockerfile) to an example of debug docker file with chrome. 
You'll find what they do to install VNC on top of the browser.

Here's what they do:

```
#=====
# VNC
#=====
RUN apt-get update -qqy \
  && apt-get -qqy install \
  x11vnc \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*

#=================
# Locale settings
#=================
ENV LANGUAGE en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 \
  && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive locales \
  && apt-get update -qqy \
  && apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install \
    language-pack-en \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*

#=======
# Fonts
#=======
RUN apt-get update -qqy \
  && apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install \
    fonts-ipafont-gothic \
    xfonts-100dpi \
    xfonts-75dpi \
    xfonts-cyrillic \
    xfonts-scalable \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*

#=========
# fluxbox
# A fast, lightweight and responsive window manager
#=========
RUN apt-get update -qqy \
  && apt-get -qqy install \
    fluxbox \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*

#==============================
# Generating the VNC password as seluser
# So the service can be started with seluser
#==============================

RUN mkdir -p ~/.vnc \
  && x11vnc -storepasswd secret ~/.vnc/passwd
```

Comment: I didn't say I used docker

Comment: @Juliana You can reproduce the same steps that are on the docker image in your VM. I'm looking for their debug image to see what's different. Which browser do you use ?

Comment: `You can reproduce the same steps that are on the docker image in your VM. ` --> that's what my question is about

Comment: @Juliana I've updated my answer with the content of one of their docker file for a debug browser.

Comment: How does VNC help you see a headless browser?

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg Well actually I focused on `The remote servers have no physical monitor/screen.` and indeed I'm not sure that it will work with the headless browsers. I'm waiting for OP feedback but he'll probably have to install normal one. I didn't think about that because I only use the docker image.